# REMOTE CONNECTION FTP

Tags: ftp

I am trying to connect FTP remotely I am getting the following error, on the local network I able to connect and access the files. please assiste

```
[22:08:16] SmartFTP v4.1.1308.0
[22:08:16] Resolving host name "41.139.214.94"
[22:08:16] Connecting to 41.139.214.94 Port: 21
[22:08:16] Connected to 41.139.214.94.
[22:08:16] 220-Microsoft FTP Service
[22:08:17] 220 SKY CITY CASINO
[22:08:17] USER ic_support
[22:08:17] 331 Password required for ic_support.
[22:08:17] PASS (hidden)
[22:08:17] 230-WELCOME
[22:08:17] 230 User ic_support logged in.
[22:08:17] SYST
[22:08:17] 215 Windows_NT
[22:08:17] Detected Server Type: Windows NT
[22:08:17] RTT: 209.609 ms
[22:08:17] FEAT
[22:08:18] 211-Extended features supported:
[22:08:18]  SIZE
[22:08:18]  MDTM
[22:08:18] 211 END
[22:08:18] Detected Server Software: Microsoft IIS FTP Service
[22:08:18] TYPE I
[22:08:18] 200 Type set to I.
[22:08:18] REST 0
[22:08:18] 350 Restarting at 0.
[22:08:18] PWD
[22:08:18] 257 "/" is current directory.
[22:08:18] TYPE A
[22:08:19] 200 Type set to A.
[22:08:19] PASV
[22:09:19] Timeout (60s).
[22:09:19] Active Help: http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/74
[22:09:19] Client closed the connection.
[22:09:19] Resolving host name "41.139.214.94"
[22:09:19] Connecting to 41.139.214.94 Port: 21
[22:09:19] Connected to 41.139.214.94.
[22:09:19] 220-Microsoft FTP Service
[22:09:19] 220 SKY CITY CASINO
[22:09:19] USER ic_support
[22:09:19] 331 Password required for ic_support.
[22:09:19] PASS (hidden)
[22:09:20] 230-WELCOME
[22:09:20] 230 User ic_support logged in.
[22:09:20] SYST
[22:09:20] 215 Windows_NT
[22:09:20] Detected Server Type: Windows NT
[22:09:20] RTT: 217.524 ms
[22:09:20] FEAT
[22:09:20] 211-Extended features supported:
[22:09:20]  SIZE
[22:09:20]  MDTM
[22:09:20] 211 END
[22:09:20] Detected Server Software: Microsoft IIS FTP Service
[22:09:20] TYPE I
[22:09:21] 200 Type set to I.
[22:09:21] REST 0
[22:09:21] 350 Restarting at 0.
[22:09:21] PWD
[22:09:21] 257 "/" is current directory.
[22:09:21] TYPE A
[22:09:21] 200 Type set to A.
[22:09:21] PASV
[22:10:22] Timeout (60s).
[22:10:22] Active Help: http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/74
[22:10:22] Client closed the connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess: your border firewall isn't open for passive FTP. Since you don't pass the firewall when connecting to an ftp server inside your own network, that works, but as soon as you have to cross the firewall, it doesn't.

Solution: talk to your firewall admins.

Comment: I tried to connect the server direct bypassed the router and firewall it did not connect